# esp32 softAP : Static IP for CLIENTS , bind MAC adress to IP adress

Tags: arduino, esp32, mac-address, static-ip-address, access-point

Is it possible to use softAP to give fixed IP addresses to clients without using the DHCP server? If not, are there any alternatives to softAP that would allow the use of an ESP 32 to assign specific IP addresses to specific MAC addresses?

I have 4 ESP32 dongles: one is used as an Access Point via softAP, the other 3 connect as clients to the first one. I would like to assign a fixed IP to each dongle. On the client side I have no problem with this. But on the Access Point side, when I check the list of connected stations, they all have IPs equal to 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that functionality is missing in ESP IDF and by extension in Arduino. The [DHCP server](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/components/lwip/apps/dhcpserver/dhcpserver.c) in ESP IDF seems to allocate IP-s sequentially in order of clients connecting in function `dhcps_poll_set()`.

As always, you can write a better DHCP server if you feel up to it :)

Comment: Yep thank you. I decided to switch to a Raspberry Pi for the Access Point part.